# Jquery не ищет элемент после перезагрузки контента через Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, odoo

Доброго времени суток!
Столкнулся с ситуацией что нужно чтобы скрипт работал с обновленным контентом который был получен от Ajax. До перезагрузки контента Скрипт работает. После считает что этих элементов нет в DOM. Элемент для скрипта находится внутри обновленного контента.
Может кто-то подсказать как можно решить эту проблему. Или подсказать где искать.

С Уважением, Lairion

Comment: А разметку и js мы сами угадать должны?

Answer (score 0):

нужно body добавить к ивенту

```
$("body").on("click", "#el", function)
```